# Combining the redundant terms in a csv file and adding their frequencies after removing the stopwords from the file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I have a csv file which looks like this -

```
    Words           Author              Frequency
    #NAME?          Pandey P            4
    OF              Hamzad Ali          135
    OF              Karen Sara          80
    A               Hamzad Ali          69
    AND             Hamzad Ali          67
    OF              Pandey P            67
    HIV-1           Hamzad Ali          49
    AND             Karen Sara          45
    IN              Hamzad Ali          44
    OF              John christopher    44
    IN              John christopher    40
    INHIBITORS      Hamzad Ali          39
    THE             Karen Sara          39
    INTEGRASE       Hamzad Ali          38
    VIRUS           Karen Sara          38
    C               Karen Sara          35
    THE             Hamzad Ali          35
    HEPATITIS       Karen Sara          34
    THE             Pandey P            34
    IN              Karen Sara          33
    KINASE          Pandey P            31
    THE             John christopher    31
    AND             Pandey P            28
    INHIBITOR       Hamzad Ali          26
    POLYMERASE      Karen Sara          26
    AND             John christopher    25
    IN              Pandey P            25
    TO              Hamzad Ali          25
    WITH            Karen Sara          25
    FOR             Hamzad Ali          23
    HCV             Karen Sara          23
    NS5B            Karen Sara          23
    HIV             Hamzad Ali          22
    NOVEL           Hamzad Ali          22
    WITH            Hamzad Ali          22
    A               Karen Sara          21
    OF              Lieberman La        21
    INHIBITOR       Karen Sara          20
    PROTEIN         Pandey P            20
    BY              Hamzad Ali          19
    INHIBITORS      Karen Sara          19
    OF              Oslund Rc           19
    OF              Wyche Tp            19
    VIRUS           Hamzad Ali          19
    HUMAN           Hamzad Ali          18
    OF              Danilchanka O       18
    OF              Hett E              17
    OF              Sana Tr             17
    A               Wyche Tp            16
    ACTIVITY        Hamzad Ali          16
    AND             Roberts L           16
    GENE            John christopher    16
    OF              Fadeyi O            16
    AND             Sana Tr             15
    OF              Roberts L           15
    RESISTANCE      Hamzad Ali          15
    REVERSE         Hamzad Ali          15
    TRANSCRIPTASE   Hamzad Ali          15
    ACID            Hamzad Ali          14
    ACTIVATION      Pandey P            14
    BY              Pandey P            14
    IN              Lieberman La        14
    PROTEASE        Karen Sara          14
    1               Hamzad Ali          13
    ANTAGONISTS     Hamzad Ali          13
    CCR5            Hamzad Ali          13
    EXPRESSION      John christopher    13
    FOR             Karen Sara          13
    HEPATITIS       Hamzad Ali          13
    IN              White Ch            13
    INFECTION       Hamzad Ali          13
    HEPATITIS       John christopher
```

I want to merge all the redundant terms and separate the count by authors. For example I want the output to be something like this -

```
    Words          Pandey P    Hamzad Ali    Karen Saha     John christopher  ..   
    HEPATITIS      47          38            32              28               ..      
    INHIBITORS     0           34            22               5       
    KINASE         45          5             0                0                ..
    HIV-1          40          35            11               25               ..      
    ...
```

Also, I want to get this output with removed english stopwords.
I don't know how to do from a coding perspective. Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions that are asking "where do I start" or for pointers are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @AChampion - Apologies for posting the question without code but I was stuck there in my project and have a deadline. I will surely take care of it from next time. Thanks for pointing that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps involved
1. get stop words
2. make dummy column to keep lower case 
3. remove records which are in stop words
4. group by Words set index as words as Author
5. unstack each group and keep Frequency

I tried this,

```
#snippet to remove stop words
stopwords_english= set(stopwords.words('english'))
df['dummy']=df['Words'].str.lower()
df=df[~df['dummy'].isin(stopwords_english)]
del df['dummy']

#snippet to get your desire result
df.groupby(['Words']).apply(lambda x:x.set_index(['Words','Author']).unstack()['Frequency'])
```

Comment: That worked well giving all the terms, even the same terms that were there in the data with and without parentheses. Thanks much!

Comment: @spideypack - I'm glad to hear this 

Comment: After updating pandas version to 0.23.1, the code supposed to give me my desired result `df.groupby(['Words']).apply(lambda x:x.set_index(['Words','Author']).unstack()['Frequency'])` which was working fine before is now giving me this error - `KeyError: 'Words'`. I believe this error was faced by some referring this - [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21075). Could you please help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @spideypack- sorry I'm using older pandas version, if it really a problem of after upgrading to new version you can raise a new question regarding this. I'll also try to solve this problem. If I found solution I'll update the solution.